# Multiple Kafka version on the same cluster

Tags: java, apache-kafka, messagebroker

Is it possible to run a Kafka cluster with brokers with different versions ?
For exemple use the version 1.1 and the version 0.11 ?

Is there some compatibility matrix ? I found a compatibility matrix client to broker, but not broker to broker.

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: Hello,
The goal is to do a rolling restart. We have a cluster in version 0.11 and we wish to upgrade to 1.1 without breaking the service.

Comment: In that case, please visit this official link for upgrade : https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation.html#upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade very old versions to newest version there might be compatibility issues, in which case you could upgrade to "intermediary" versions on your way to the last version.

If not, Kafka does support running different versions in the same cluster for rolling upgrades.

**EDIT:**

When you upgrade your servers, you can define which protocol to use between the brokers using `inter.broker.protocol.version`

More info: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade

Comment: Hello,
The articles you refers to are about client to broker compatibility, not broker to broker compatibility.